# Creating Setup of large data with NSIS Script

Tags: installation, nsis, large-files

I am creating setup of large data approximetly 10 GB with NSIS Script and trying to create a single setup (exe). Its giving an Error -

Internal compiler error #12345: error mmapping file (xxxxxxxxxx, xxxxxxxx) is out of range.

Note: you may have one or two (large) stale temporary file(s) left in your temporary directory (Generally this only happens on Windows 9x).

Please tell me how to solve this issue ?
Is there any other way to create a setup for this kinda situation ?

Answer (score 6):

NSIS installers are limited to 2Gb.

If you absolutely need it to be one file and you want to continue to use NSIS you have to append the data to the end of the generated setup. I'm not sure I would recommend that approach but it could work if the appended data is a zip file (or some other format with the header at the end) and you use one of the NSIS zip plugins to extract at run-time...

Comment: Anders is right. What about splitting the installer into .exe (up to 2GB) and several .zip or .cab archives? This is also common for DVD or CD (also Floppy disk :) distribution.

Answer (score 5):

I have used https://sourceforge.net/projects/nsisbi/ instead of normal NSIS. It solved the problem.

Comment: nsisbi solved my big instal lfile issue! Abour 3.2 GB. I was using electron build, si I overwrote all C:\Users\XXXXXX\AppData\Local\electron-builder\Cache\nsis\nsis-3.0.4.2 files and voila!

Answer (score 1):

I was using Silent Install Builder 5 and received this same error with a package installer that had LESS that 2 GB total. Once I determined that the NSIS compiler was to blame, I began experimenting with several possible solutions and here's what worked: I downloaded the newer NSISBI compiler from here https://sourceforge.net/projects/nsisbi/ and then did these 3 steps:

1. Go to C:\Program Files (x86)\Silent Install Builder 5 and renamed the default NSIS folder to a new name.
2. Copied the NSISBI folder into the C:\Program Files (x86)\Silent Install Builder 5 directory and renamed IT to NSIS.
3. Tries to compile some large packages above and just below 2GB and the first few tries I would get missing file errors in the Silent Install Builder 5 compiling box. No worries because the missing  files are in the old NSIS folder, that's why y9u don't delete it.
4. Each time find the missing file error displays, find the missing files and copy them into the same folder location in the new NSIS folder. About 3 times you will do this until there are no more errors at all and you can then include the large files without generating the "internal compiler error #12345: error mmapping file xxxx is out of range." error message. NSISBI works!

Comment: I use NSISBI to get large installers working, but when trying to include files into the installer that are larger than 2GB themselves, it still gives this error.

Answer (score 0):

After some research and chin scratching a really simple solution made me head-palm. Include an assets zip along with the NSIS install.exe, then in the first Section run

```
nsExec::ExecToStack 'cmd /c "tar -xf $EXEDIR\Install_deps.zip -C  $INSTDIR"'
```

This worked for me.