# NSIS : 'Internal compiler error #12345:'

Tags: nsis

I am new to NSIS. I want to create a setup using 8 gb database. I tried to create this and got error 'Internal compiler error #12345: error mapping file (1429600644, 33554432) is out of range'. Can anybody tell me how to solve this error ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Refer this question...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21108762/creating-setup-of-large-data-with-nsis-script....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating Setup of large data with NSIS Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21108762/creating-setup-of-large-data-with-nsis-script)

Answer (score 1):

Your installer exceeds NSIS' limit of 2GB. You can overcome this with the [WinImage](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/WimImage_plug-in) plugin.